# Java 9 - REST with Spring 5 & Jigsaw - Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, java-9

I've been looking into JDK 9's Jigsaw modular system.

It works quite nicely when compiling from the command line (at least the [quickstart](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) does).

But I'm trying to create a simple REST API using Spring and Jigsaw. [Spring 5.0.0 M1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-the-Spring-Framework#whats-new-in-spring-framework-5x) is said to have

> Full compatibility with JDK 9 as of July 2016

I also want the REST API to work with Maven. According to [this Maven page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw),
Maven should be able to work with Java 9 (or am I reading this wrong?).

When having my JAVA_HOME point to my JDK, I cannot seem to run `mvn spring-boot:run` on my Spring Boot application - it throws a lot of exceptions, such as:

```
FoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
2016-09-14 10:43:42.704 ERROR 120408 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Running `mvn -version` gives me:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 9-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Is it currently possible to create this REST API with Spring and Java 9 using Jigsaw? Or should I stick to Java 8 until around March/July 2017?

Full stack dump:

```
2016-09-14 10:43:42.688  WARN 120408 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:                          Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.bea                         ns.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedS                         ervletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot                         /autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.clas                         s]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans                         .factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.spri                         ngframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied d                         ependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with na                         me 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncoding                         Properties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClas                         sDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException; nested exception is org.spri                         ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '                         spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProp                         erties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDef                         FoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
2016-09-14 10:43:42.704 ERROR 120408 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory'                          defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/Embed                         dedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of be                         an failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDepe                         ndencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autocon                         figure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed thro                         ugh constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding                         -org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initializat                         ion of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xm                         l/bind/ValidationException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factor                         y.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org                         .springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization                          of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bi                         nd/ValidationException
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:535) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-ea/Thread.java:843) [na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAut                         oConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exce                         ption is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error                          creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodin                         gAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parame                         ter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.b                         oot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; ne                         sted exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationExcep                         tion; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExceptio                         n: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.                         autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested                          exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor para                         meter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework                         .boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed;                          nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationExc                         eption; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcept                         ion: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boo                         t.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nest                         ed exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationExcepti                         on
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

---- cut off

Summary Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin                         
:1.4.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project gs-rest-service: An exception occurr                         
ed while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded cont                         
ainer; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcepti       
on: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' define                         
d in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedSer
vletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean fai                    
led; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependency              
Exception: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure    
.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through co                         
nstructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.s           
pringframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of                          
bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind                         
/ValidationException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bean                      
CreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.sprin            
gframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bea                         
n failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/Val                         
idationException: javax.xml.bind.ValidationException -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Add the whole stack, we'd actually like to see what exception you're getting. "Application startup failed" is of no use to us.

Comment: Just snip out the most low-level exception. [How to read a stacktrace](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-read-stack-traces-and-troubleshoot-your-own-plugins-by-yourself.32457/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using non-default modules you need to add it manually when you compile and run Java9:

```
javac --add-modules java.xml.bind ...
java  --add-modules java.xml.bind ...
```

If there are other missing java ee classes try adding the barrel module:

```
--add-module java.se.ee
```

Answer (score 3):

rorschach's answer is not correct because hibernate validation exception is in a different package, different class.  I don't have enough rep points to comment directly.

zhy2002's answer is correct for the Java-9-only case but won't work for Java 8 or 10 (because this java ee module is deprecated and will be removed in 10).  If you want it to work with Java 8 and Java 9 as we do, you can add this dependency:

Gradle:

```
compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
```

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See here:
[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Answer (score 2):

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException: javax.xml.bind.ValidationException
```

You're missing a dependency, specifically [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final).

Comment: which implicitly is caused by using Java 9 as JDK, since this REST API is using Spring-boot and there is yet no spring-boot release compatable with JDK9/modules? Or is there?

Comment: Did you add the dependency? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

In case of Spring Boot you need to add in maven pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <jvmArguments>--add-modules java.xml.bind</jvmArguments>
         <mainClass>org.springframework.samples.petclinic.PetClinicApplication</mainClass>
     </configuration>
...
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
             <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See https://blog.frankel.ch/migrating-to-java-9/2/